# Java script reading CSV returns a string as a column of values. How to extract each value?

Tags: java, csv

Im trying to read a CSV file but the return is a whole column of values,
how can I use each row individually (been working with java for 4 days now, so please be nice to my incapability :D)

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.*;


public class CSVData {

    private static final String FILE_PATH="D:\\eclipse\\250.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH));
        String [] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            String a = nextLine[2];
            System.out.println(a);
        }

    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

Gender
female
male
male
female
female
female
male

I want to be able to use each row as a separate value, for example nextLine[2][1] but it doesnt work

Comment: Does it return each row like : `a,b,c,d,e` or returns the entire column ?

Comment: Oh, now I see I havent formatted the text right. The values are at separate lines. I can get each column of the csv this way, but I dont know how to get a certain row

Comment: Basically, I'd like to be able to turn that column into an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to read the whole thing first and assign it to a list or array as you go. Here's something quick from me, assuming your csv has five columns (I am not sure how to get the number of columns dynamically):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH));
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++) { //i<5 is hardcoded; get actual function for number of columns
           list.add(nextLine[i]);
        }
        array.add(list);
    }
    // example for nested loop to display results
    for(x=0;x<array.size();x++) {
        for(y=0;y<array.get(x).size();y++) {
            System.out.print(array.get(x).get(y) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    // example to display specific item
    System.out.println(array.get(1).get(1));
}
```

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this (an object to hold the table data then placed in a list is better) but you get the idea. You can later use list.get(x) or list.get(x).get(y) and loops to retrieve the data.

Comment: array.add(new String[]={nextLine[0],nextLine[1],nextLine[2],nextLine[3],nextline[4]});This line turned red into eslipse, the message is: Array constants can only be used in initializers

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
are these the correct imports?

Comment: Thank you, I got following results (system out println (list))
[FirstName, LastName, Gender, City, Email]
[Portia, Mcfann, female, San Diego, portia@mcfann.com]
[Andrew, Fenstermacher, male, Perry, andrew@fenstermacher.com]

Comment: but how do I get the results now? I tried list.get(x).get(y), but I have never declared x and y, how do I declare them in this case? And what kind of loop should I use?

Comment: x and y are just placeholders, they refer to the indexes of the arrays. In your current list, for example, `list.get(0).get(0)` will return 'FirstName'. Use nested `for` loops to get the data.

Comment: when I use that, the second "get" becomes red and the error message reads: "The method get(int) is undefined for the type String"

Comment: Ah, wait, in my example, array is the name of the nested list. Use `array.get(x).get(y)`. If you're using a nested `for` loop, this assumes that you use x for the outer loop and y for inner.

Comment: Im so sorry to be that annoying, but I still can't figure it out..          array.add(list);
         String asd = array.get(1).get(2);
         System.out.println(asd);
Nothing is outputted

Comment: Place your code after the while loop, since you're placing your code when array isn't populated yet.

Comment: when I place it outside the while loop, it doesnt recognize the "list" variable anymore.

Comment: I've edited in code to my response to demonstrate how this works, and the loop too, I assumed your code started from `String asd`.